# Function to replace color in .bmp

Tags: optimization, c, image, io

I wrote a function to replace color in a bitmap image. For beginners in image processing, it could be exclusively useful, since they could use it to replace the entire gamma of a color or to replace a color with gradient/abstract lines, following the function's logic.

The main problem of the function, according to performance, is that it isn't fast enough.
For larger images/replacing more then one color, this could take a minute or even more.
I am sure there is a huge room for improvement of this function, therefore speed-optimized.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define IMAGE_WIDTH         500
#define IMAGE_OFFSET_SIZE   2
#define IMAGE_OFFSET_PIXELS 54

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned long dword;

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    dword bitmap_color_replace (char *, byte, byte, byte, byte, byte, byte);

    printf("Pixels successfully replaced: %i\n",
    bitmap_color_replace("sample.bmp", 255, 255, 255, 0, 200, 255));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/**************************************************************************/

dword
bitmap_color_replace
(char *file_name, byte old_r, byte old_g, byte old_b, byte new_r, byte new_g, byte new_b)
{
    dword fp_height = 0;
    dword fp_size;
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "r+b");
    dword i, pixels_replaced = 0;

    byte new_color[3];

    new_color[0] = new_b;
    new_color[1] = new_g;
    new_color[2] = new_r;

    fseek(fp, IMAGE_OFFSET_SIZE, SEEK_SET);
    fp_size = fgetc(fp) + fgetc(fp)*256 + fgetc(fp)*(256*256) + fgetc(fp)*(256*256*256);

    for(i = IMAGE_OFFSET_PIXELS; i < fp_size; i += sizeof(new_color))
    {
        byte current_r, current_g, current_b;

        fseek(fp, i, SEEK_SET);

        if(i == IMAGE_OFFSET_PIXELS + (IMAGE_WIDTH * (fp_height+1))) // skip padding
        {
            fp_height++;
            i += IMAGE_WIDTH % 4;
            fseek(fp, IMAGE_WIDTH % 4, SEEK_CUR);
        }

        current_b = fgetc(fp);
        current_g = fgetc(fp);
        current_r = fgetc(fp);

        if(current_b == old_b && current_g == old_g && current_r == old_r)
        {
            fseek(fp, i, SEEK_SET);
            fwrite(new_color, sizeof(new_color), 1, fp);
            pixels_replaced++;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return pixels_replaced;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered loading the whole file or at least chunks of it in memory, doing the replacement there and then saving the results, all in as few I/O operations as possible?

Comment: I did.. but I also need it directly.

Comment: And have you actually ran some benchmarks to see if the I/O isn't your bottleneck? Because if it is, then you're not in luck.

Comment: What are you even trying to state? I am confused..

Comment: I was suggesting that I/O is *slow* and since you're doing so many I/O operations I would have ran some benchmarks to see if I/O is the cause for poor performance. Then, I said that if I/O is the cause for poor performance in your code, there's nothing you can do since you said that you need to do the replacement directly. Rule for performance optimization: benchmark to find the cause for bad performance, and rework that. I don't think your question is against the rules here, just that I would have appreciated it if you first tried to find the cause for the poor performance yourself.

Comment: Perhaps benchmarking was not the most appropriate term. Profiling would have probably been better?

Comment: Why would I ask for a review if the code works perfectly? Well, in my opinion it is slow, because of the number of operations it has to perform. That number could be reduced by changing the method. Once i heard that `fseek` is slow. Multiply that by the size of the image..

Comment: **"Why would I ask for a review if the code works perfectly?"** For one thing, because as a programmer your goal should be to write the best code you can. Code that is bug-free, scalable, readable and maintainable by you and by others. You ask for code review to improve those aspects. If the code is not working, it is not even ready for review.

Comment: @glampert Okay, the code works perfectly, it is written with pretty good mechanism /maybe bad code/ and it is relatively fast, it is readable, maintainable, scalable, bug-gree. And I am looking for improvement of this aspects. Especially the one that bothers the performance.

Comment: You should really take Alex M's advice and read the file into a buffer.  You will avoid all the `fgetc`, `fseek`, and `fwrite` calls.  You can also do better by optimizing your search methodology.  For example, if you examine `b` and it doesn't match `old_b`, then there is no need to examine `r` or `g`.  You can just skip ahead to the next color triplet.  I don't understand the requirement of replacing colors "directly".  Why would you need to do that?  What does that even mean?

Comment: @JS1 Let me tell you then. The project I work on uses two methods for each function _direct and _data. It is not hard for you to manage what is the difference. _data requires more memory resources and it isn't safe but is faster, while _direct is slower, but is securer and doesn't require buffering.

Comment: Over-Examining is an idea of mine, which is used to re-check pixel in case something happened and it wasn't replaced.

Comment: Why is it securer? `fwrite` and `fgetc` are both buffered so I don't see the difference.  You could use 'mmap' instead of file io if you care about memory usage.  I think the main thing is that you didn't list all your requirements in the question.  You only stated that you wanted your code to run faster.  I'm still not clear on what you are "securing" against.  Are multiple processes operating on these files?  Are you afraid of running out of memory?

Comment: @JS1 Well if it wasn't described in the question, I think it became pretty much obvious after the second comment here. I simply said that I need this directly. I have my reasons. On the engine I am coding.. considering the fact It has many buffers, waiting to be free'd.. yes. I am afraid of filling a lot of memory.

Comment: A lot of times people say "I must do X" but when someone else comes in and asks enough questions, it becomes clear that they didn't really need to do X, they were only trying to solve a particular problem that could be solved with a better solution Y.  I'm just trying to ask these questions because nothing you have said so far has convinced me of the necessity of all this file io.  You say you have your reasons, but if don't say them, we can't help you.

Comment: I said them. Not like I believe you could help anyway.. but let me just repeat. I can not afford one more buffer. Especially if it is huge. My project consists of _direct and _data io functions. One performed directly, other to/from buffer..

Comment: `new_color[2] = nre_r;`  Is this `nre_r` declared somewhere?  I doubt it'll compile otherwise.

Comment: `new_r` I suppose thats what i meant. If it matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some ways in which this code might be improved.

### Make sure `printf` format specifiers match the data

In the sample `main`, the format specifier used is `"%i"` but `bitmap_color_replace` returns a `dword` which is an alias for `unsigned long`, so the correct format specifier would actually be `"%lu"` for that data.

### Omit return statement in `main`

This line

```
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

is not needed with modern C compilers. Getting to the end of `main` implicitly means that the program has succeeded, so the compiler will include code to do that return if you simply omit it.

### Rearrange the code to reduce the need for declarations

A function declaration is only needed by the compiler if it hasn't already encountered the function itself.  With that said, if the `bitmap_color_replace` function is moved to the top of the file, above `main`, the function declaration within `main` can be omitted, making `main` a single `printf`.

### Omit unused variables

Because `argc` and `argv` are unused, you could use the alternative form of `main`:

```
int main ()
```

### Avoid hardcoding values

The `IMAGE_WIDTH`, `IMAGE_OFFSET_PIXELS` are not valid for most images.  Rather than hardcode those, you could simply read them from the file header in the same way that `fp_size` is read.

### Avoid uneccessary `fseek` calls

There are a lot of `fseek` calls within the current routine which are not necessary because the program moves linearly through the data anyway.  Eliminating them would likely speed up the program.

### Calculate pad size just once

The padding size is the same for every row so you can calulate it based on the image width and the size of each color.

### Process only the pixel data

In some version of BMP files, there is data after the pixel data, so the current code, which continues to the end of the physical file, would overwrite that data.  Better would be to calculate just the size of the pixel data which is obtained from the height and width of the image.

### Don't overwrite the input file

Create a new file instead of overwriting the input file.  This helps the user as well as preventing file corruption if something goes wrong during the processing of the file. It may also speed the program.

### Process larger chunks at a time in memory

Instead of reading the colors byte at a time, it would likely speed things up considerably by processing entire rows at a time, or even the entire file as a memory image.  I/O is often the bottleneck for programs like this, so minimizing it can result in considerable time savings.

### Note the correct data order

BMP files contain pixel data as R,G,B in that order.  It's important to get the order right to correctly match colors.

### One possibility

Here's a version of the code with some, but not all of these ideas incorporated:

```
// these are absolute offsets to the two most important 
// items in the BMP file 
#define IMAGE_PIXEL_START   10
#define IMAGE_WIDTH         18

typedef unsigned char byte;
typedef unsigned long dword;

dword
bitmap_color_replace
(char *file_name, byte old_r, byte old_g, byte old_b, byte new_r, byte new_g, byte new_b)
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(file_name, "r+b");
    dword pixels_replaced = 0;

    byte new_color[3];

    new_color[0] = new_r;
    new_color[1] = new_g;
    new_color[2] = new_b;

    byte old_color[3];

    fseek(fp, IMAGE_PIXEL_START, SEEK_SET);
    dword fp_pixelstart = fgetc(fp) + fgetc(fp)*256 + fgetc(fp)*(256*256) + fgetc(fp)*(256*256*256);
    fseek(fp, IMAGE_WIDTH, SEEK_SET);
    dword fp_width = fgetc(fp) + fgetc(fp)*256 + fgetc(fp)*(256*256) + fgetc(fp)*(256*256*256);
    dword fp_height = fgetc(fp) + fgetc(fp)*256 + fgetc(fp)*(256*256) + fgetc(fp)*(256*256*256);
    // rows are padded to a multiple of 4 bytes
    dword padsize = (4 - ( (sizeof(new_color) * fp_width) & 0x3 )) & 0x3;

    fseek(fp, fp_pixelstart, SEEK_SET);
    for (int row = fp_height; row; --row) 
    {
        for (int col = fp_width; col; --col) 
        {
            fread(old_color, sizeof(old_color), 1, fp);
            if(    old_color[0] == old_r 
                && old_color[1] == old_g 
                && old_color[2] == old_b)
            {
                fseek(fp, -sizeof(old_color), SEEK_CUR);
                fwrite(new_color, sizeof(new_color), 1, fp);
                pixels_replaced++;
            }
        }
        if (padsize)
        {
            fseek(fp, padsize, SEEK_CUR);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return pixels_replaced;
}
```